# Is it possible to convert HDMI out to VGA?

Tags: hdmi, vga

I need to convert HDMI output to a VGA monitor.
I don't care about audio. I need just 1920x1080. I can use both a HDMI cable or a VGA cable, less than a meter distance. Do these passive converters work?

[image: hdmi to vga cable]

I read on the internet it needs to be powered. But at the same time I see that these things work:

[image: hdmi to vga cable with box]

Which are also not powered. So what makes them work? The bigger case? :P Do you think it's realistic the first one is not just a fraud?

Comment: If you aren't sure a device will fit your need look for a trusted store where they buy it back if it doesn't work as expected. We can't tell you from a random image whether a device is fraudulent.

Comment: Most of these cheap converters DO work, but as they often use "parasitic power" one could expect the power provider (the image source?) to be hampered or get a shorter life time. Additionally you might expect some level of image degradation, maybe not on a digital transformation though. The actual facts may differ from case to case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HDMI pinout, HDMI (unlike DVI) only transfers **digital** signals. VGA needs **analog** signals.

The means **there are no passive HDMI to VGA cables**. **All** VGA to HDMI cables contain electronics, which implement a complete HDMI receiver and a VGA output, and need to be powered (from the HDMI power pins, you don't need ab extra power brick).

The "bigger case" is where the electronics are. Sometimes the electronics are small enough you don't notice them in the plugs.

Answer (score -1):

Both the images you have listed are actually adapters. No they do not need to be powered, it will draw the required power from the HDMI Port. Also they both will work.

With both of these you will still need to use/buy an extra VGA Cable.

- So instead I suggest you buy this (hdmi to vga cable) :
  [https://www.amazon.com/NewBEP-Gold-Plated-Converter-Notebook-Projector/dp/B01NBOQP1F/ref=sr_1_3?crid=EADZ0AO2FNSK&keywords=hdmi+to+vga+cable+with+audio&qid=1572159196&sprefix=hdmi+to+vga+cable+%2Caps%2C400&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NBOQP1F)
- Even if you don't care about the audio, you can leave the audio cable unplugged but who knows you might need it in the future so better to have it, there's not any major cost difference.
- Also with this, you wont need an extra VGA cable
- You can choose what length you want (assuming you buy it from this link).